# Serving a video asset suitable for the user's connection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, vimeo

I am currently building a web page that has an 8 second background video as a full view width and view height hero asset. The video is hosted in vimeo, youtube is sadly not an option for me due to my clients preferences.

Here is my HTML code so far:

```
<video autoplay playsinline muted loop>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="/my-vimeo-video.hd.mp4">
  <source type="video/webm" src="/my-vimeo-video.hd.mp4">
</video>
```

Currently the video is working as I would like it to on desktop and on mobile with a ‘good’ wifi connection. However the issue arrises when on a bad connection with a mobile. As the page loads the user will see the video loading before it is able to start playing.

Ideally I would like to detect the user's connection speed and serve a video asset suitable for the connection speed. The default video would be hd but if the connection is not good then I could serve a lower quality video.

Is something like this possible? If not how would a web developer usually get around the issue of serving the best video asset possible to the user based on the user’s connection speed?

Essentially I would like to avoid a situation where the user navigates to the page to see a video trying to load.

I have briefly looked at the Network information API but this is not a viable option for me due to the lack of support on safari.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: your best bet is to not reinvent the wheel and just encode and serve a multi-bitrate source like HLS or MPEG-DASH and use a player that supports it (most modern browsers support HLS natively, and players like Plyr.io or Shaka support mpeg-dash)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the answer here is to use a technology like DASH, which can have adaptive bitrate changes mid-stream.  All of the major DASH players have decently tuned bitrate switching built-in, when supported by the source.  If you use Vimeo's player, this will be handled for you.

> web page that has an 8 second background video

In this case, switching bitrate mid-stream isn't useful to you.  By the time you have enough data to make a determination, the file would have been downloaded already.

What I would recommend instead is making a file of the lowest acceptable quality bitrate, and serving that to everyone.  I would recommend having a static image background as a fallback for those that don't have the bandwidth to quickly load your background video.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a quick way would be to measure the speed of the user's connection then based of those speeds on the client side decide what video to get. And depending on those conditions perform a client-side redirect.

```
var imageAddr = "http://www.tranquilmusic.ca/images/cats/Cat2.JPG" + "?n=" + Math.random();
var startTime, endTime;
var downloadSize = 5616998;
var download = new Image();
download.onload = function () {
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    showResults();
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;

function showResults() {
    var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    if (speedMbps > requiredSpeed) {
     window.location.replace("http://you-website.com/video?heigher_quality=True");
     } else {
       window.location.replace("http://you-website.com/video?heigher_quality=False");  
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ideally I would prefer not to need to do a client side redirect but this function is really helpful!

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: Using an express server

Comment: This is the wrong answer for the question at hand.  It's important for streaming media applications to be adaptive to the state of the network and playback in as realtime as possible.  Downloading some large file to determine available bandwidth is a waste of time, bandwidth, does not adapt to changing conditions, and does not validate the speed of that user being able to get at the media files anyway.